# In inferential statistics, is the noncentrality parameter of the F-distribution simply the F-value 'in the population'?

Tags: statistical-power, inference, f-distribution, non-central

I'm writing functions (in `R`) that allow working with the $\omega^2$ distribution (the effect size for analysis of variance; the less biased alternative to $\eta^2$). Not being a mathematician or statistician, I do this by converting between $\omega^2$ and $F$ and vice versa (only working on the oneway anova scenario so far).

This works well so far (functions implemented in package `userfriendlyscience` 0.5-1, see [`?pomegaSq`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/userfriendlyscience/versions/0.5-0/topics/omegaSqDist) if anybody runs into this question because they need those functions) but now I want to add the noncentrality parameter.

For the $t$-distribution, the noncentrality parameter is equal to the $t$-value corresponding to the expected effect in the population (I used the same trick for a Cohen's $d$ distribution). This was simple enough for me to could play around with to be pretty sure that's how it works.

However, for the $F$-distribution, I'm not certain enough that here, the noncentrality parameter is indeed also the relevant $F$-value. For example, assuming $N=100$ participants, $k=3$ groups, and an effect size of $\omega^2 = .06$ (i.e. a 'medium' effect), is it true that the noncentrality parameter of the corresponding $F$-distribution (from which the $F$-value of any given sample of $N=100$ is drawn) is equal to:

```
convert.omegasq.to.f(.06, 3 - 1, 100 - 3);
[1] 4.191489
```

(This function is again from `userfriendlyscience`)

Or, in a formula:

$$ \frac{\omega^2 \frac{df2 + 1}{df1} + 1}{1 - \omega^2} =
\frac{.06 \frac{97 + 1}{2} + 1}{1 - .06} =
\frac{3.94}{.94} = 4.191489$$

(assuming this formula is correct; it was derived by a colleague of mine who is in fact a statistician)

If this is correct, then that would mean that this would work:

```
domegaSq <- function(x, df1, df2, populationOmegaSq = 0) {
  return(df(convert.omegasq.to.f(x, df1, df2), df1, df2,
            ncp = convert.omegasq.to.f(populationOmegaSq, df1, df2)));
}
```

And the distribution of omega squared could be drawn, for example for no effect (grey, $\omega^2=0$), a small effect (red, $\omega^2=0.01$), a medium effect (orange, $\omega^2=0.06$) and a large effect (green, $\omega^2=0.14$) and $N=100$ and $k=3$:

[image: The distribution of omega squared]

Does anybody know whether the crucial assumption in this procedure (the noncentrality parameter of the $F$-distribution is the expected value of $F$) is correct?

Comment: I found [this explanation](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2036567) by Conrad Carlberg, where he uses:

$$\lambda = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^k \beta^2_j}{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}} = \frac{SS_\text{effect}}{MS_\text{error}}$$

Because

$$F = \frac{\frac{SS_\text{effect}}{k-1}}{MS_\text{error}} = \frac{1}{k-1}\frac{SS_\text{effect}}{MS_\text{error}}$$

this would mean that

$$\lambda = \frac{F}{\frac{1}{k-1}} = (k - 1)F$$

And

$$F = \frac{\lambda}{k-1}$$

For situations with equal group sizes.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Check Liu and Raudenbush, eq. 4b, http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.3102/10769986029002251

Comment: Great, that paper covers exactly this - how can I have missed this? Thank you very much!